# Full sms message has not been sent while sending sms through sendgrid c#

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, sms, sendgrid

I want send sms through SMS gateway using send grid.
I am using following code for sending sms.

```cs
var sendgrid_message = new SendGridMessage();

sendgrid_message.AddTo(toNumber@domainname);

//set the sender
sendgrid_message.From = new MailAddress(from_address);

//set the message body
// sendgrid_message.Html = message;
sendgrid_message.Html = string.Format(" ");

//set the message subject
sendgrid_message.Subject ="The profile has been updated successfully. If you have not done this, please contact administrator.";

sendgrid_message.Text = "The profile has been updated successfully. If you have not done this, please contact administrator.";

//create an instance of the Web transport mechanism
var transportInstance = new Web(new NetworkCredential(username, password));

//send the mail
await transportInstance.DeliverAsync(sendgrid_message);
```

But I am not getting full content in SMS message. 
I got message in following way

```
'The profile has been updated successfully. If you
'
```

Even if I use SMTP also, I am not getting full content.

Where am I wrong?

Do I need to follow another way to SMS?

Please let me know.

Comment: It seems you have hit maximum character limit for an sms allowed by Sendgrid and the remaining message is truncated.

Comment: Try to split your message string  so that its inside the character limit and sent it as multiple sms

Comment: Even if I use SMTP i am not getting full content. But if I send mail directly we are getting full content

Comment: Change the Sendgrid.HTML to the same message you're using in .Text . Do not utilize the string.format(" "); there...  Also, change your .Subject for something with LESS characters. Try.